# Good AMD GC but only find "SCRAPPER" where there should be a compute drop down menu

Tags: rendering, gpu, opencl

I have been trying to get my AMD Radeon card to finally be recognized by Blender. It was working beautifully then I installed the Sensei Format and all of a sudden I lose my ability to render with GPU.

I was using Blender 2.79 and had to downgrade to 2.78c to get the OpenCL option to enable but now Under it all I get is Scrapper.....[image: No Drop-down Menu, Just scrapper]

I have GPU selected in the settings to the right. It used to be grayed out even before. Now it is not. But where did all my card options go in the drop-down window. It was replaced with Scrapper.... when I turn scrapper on, and hit render whilst using GPU, Blender crashes

Here is My DXDiag:

Windows 7 Professional 64-bit (6.1, Build 7601) Service Pack 1 (7601.win7sp1_ldr.170512-0600)
           Language: English (Regional Setting: English)
System Manufacturer: Hewlett-Packard
       System Model: HP Compaq Pro 6305 SFF
               BIOS: Default System BIOS
          Processor: AMD A4-5300B APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics    (2 CPUs), ~3.4GHz
             Memory: 8192MB RAM
Available OS Memory: 7630MB RAM
          Page File: 3577MB used, 11681MB available
        Windows Dir: C:\Windows
    DirectX Version: DirectX 11
DX Setup Parameters: Not found
   User DPI Setting: Using System DPI
 System DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
    DWM DPI Scaling: Disabled
     DxDiag Version: 6.01.7601.17514 32bit Unicode

Here is my UP...

[image: User Preferences]

Comment: UPDATE: Apparently Scrapper is the Device's code name. Now to figure out why it crashes blender to Render using GPU

Comment: So far no real fix found....I have searched every possible search combination in google to figure this out. I did, however, figure out that "Scrapper" is the code name for the GPU Compute my card uses. So I will attempt a further research using Scrapper when refering to GPU or my AMD CCard

Comment: Absolutely NO References to Scrapper. I did come across a release notes for 2.78c that shows a picture. In that picture Scrapper was in the Compute Device area just like mine. the user was also using the same exact card and blender build on the same Win 7 OS. the user also used it with NO problem....Why am I having this issue?.....There has got to be something that can fix this.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is simple. Scrapper is the code name for the GPU Device used on my card. The reason Blender crashes when it begins to load the Kernels, is because my graphics card only has 512MB Memory. So when the loading starts, It uses up the entire 512MB of memory, then crashes when it realizes it needs more and can't get it (so-to-speak). My card is supported, I just need to get  one with more memory. :D

[image]

Comment: Didn't like my answer? lol